# How to search double digit numbers in python with regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have a piece of code that records times in this format:

```
    0.0-8.0
    0.0-9.0
    0.0-10.0
```

I want to use a regular expression that will find all of these strings and have checked [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html) for help but am still confused. I understand how to do it if I only wanted to do single digit numbers, but I can't figure out how to handle double digit numbers like 10 or 20.

It is also important that the expression does not find the string

```
0.0-1.0
```

as it should be ignored. 
So far my expression looks like this:

```
    expression = re.compile(',0\.0\-[0-2][0-9])
```

Comment: Is the comma in your regex intentional?

Comment: what are you actually trying to match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to match each line shown in your question, try an expression like this:

```
0\.0\-[0-2]?\d\.\d
```

`\d` is the same as `[0-9]`. The `?` means 0 or 1 occurrences, so this will only match 1- or 2-digit numbers. If you need the comma at the start of the regex, add that in.

If you want to exclude `0.0-1.0`, then you should do that in code, not in the regular expression, since that would make it less readable. But if you insist, I have included one that will exclude that string for you:

[**Try it here**](http://pythex.org/?regex=0%5C.0%5C-%5B0-2%5D%3F%5B0-9%5D%5C.(%3F%3C!0-1%5C.)%5Cd&test_string=Match%20these%3A%0A0.0-8.0%0A0.0-9.0%0A0.0-10.0%0A%0ANot%20this%3A%0A0.0-1.0&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

```
0\.0\-[0-2]?[0-9]\.(?<!0-1\.)\d
```

This uses a negative lookbehind to ensure the previous part is not `0-1.`, which would only occur in the match you didn't want.